# How to recover the port on balanced servers

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web-applications

My webapp is over a balanced servers, it works with Tomcat.

These tomcat are on different servers as normal.

In this last days we added a new Tomcat service in the same machine on a different port for our personal tests.

So we have this configuration:

Serv1:8845

Serv2:8845

Serv2:8945

balanced in testmyapp:443 because it is in https.

So when I typing https://testmyapp:443/myapp, I recover the IP of the Serv2 through NetworkInterface, but I don't succeed to recover the port.
I have to know in which port of the server the request is started (8845 or 8945) , because one of this service was created for another purpose.

How can I recover this type of information?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access to the listening port with the [HTTPServletRequest](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) object, see its [getLocalPort](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getLocalPort--) method.

By the way, there is a similar method returning the listening IP. NetworkInterface looks somewhat out of context in your case.

Comment: @DarioFerrante You're wellcome and thanks for the reputation.